# How can I upload files in AngularJS with $resource?

Tags: java, angularjs, file-upload

I want to upload the files from the client side using AngularJS with $resource.

Need to send the FormData to the server.

I am trying with the following code

## MyFile.tpl.html

```
<input file-model="uploadingfile" type="file"/><br/>
```

## MyDirective.js

```
angular.module('upload.upload', [
])

 .directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
  }]);
```

## MyController.js

```
var myservercall = $resource("my/rest/path/:filename", { filename: '@filename'});

var file = $scope.uploadingfile;
var fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('upload', file);
 myservercall.save({filename: file.name}, here i don't know how to send the form data);
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: What sort of files? What does the upload function currently look like? Angular is a client-side MVC framework. What are you using for the server side? That's going to be how the code is implemented; you'll have very little of it in Angular (at best it'll just be an Angular Resource).  Do you have a REST endpoint to upload files to?

Comment: Yes I am using REST end point to upload files. My server-side is EJB

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to get the data of the file added to the file input element.  There are any number of ways to implement it, but this will give you access to the data you need to POST to your api.